# How to see laravel view without php Artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, webserver

How can I see the `Laravel` view without an artisan command `CLI`. I don't have `CLI` from my hosting provider, I only have access to `FTP`, to run `Laravel` I have to use this command in `CLI`:

```
php artisan serve --port=8080 --host=0.0.0.0
```

How can I get the view without this command?

Thanks.

Comment: can you be more specific - what kind of commands do you want to run from controller and model ?

Comment: I wanted to know how to start laravel without the CLI

Comment: if you kno CodeIngniter you can just upload your files to your server folder, viya ftp or anything else, and it will work, will laravel work the same way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`php artisan serve` is **not** ment for use in production environments because it uses PHP5 build in webserver. If you're with a hosting provider, they probably run Apache and you can just serve your app via Apache.

Have a look at [the documentation on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) if you want to know more about the build in webserver.

> **PHP applications will stall if a request is blocked.**
>
> This web server was designed to aid application development. It may also be useful for testing purposes or for application demonstrations that are run in controlled environments. It is not intended to be a full-featured web server. It should not be used on a public network.

Comment: Laravel will work with apache? I have a conntroller that makes a view:

`localhost:8000/user`

but I cannot acces it with apache running on my local host:
http://localhost/laravel-project/user

how is is it going to be with the hosting? and how will it be viewed there?

Comment: This answer is wrong. I am using artisan commands on my server (fortrabbit). They offer direct access to application through terminal/SSH.

Comment: @aks007: use `laravel-project/public` (and make sure .htaccess is set up properly, but laravel does that for you). @carousel: I'm talking about `php artisan serve` not other artisan commands. You can perfectly use those while on production.

Comment: Yes, Laravel works with Apache; it's supposed to be used with Apache (or nginx, etc). But without a CLI you're going to have a tough time working with Laravel.