# Styles and scripts not running in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I import styles and scripts in a `view.blade.php` like this

[image: Figure 1]

But when I run the project, none of these styles are running:

[image: Figure 2]

My source:

[image: Figure 3]

This project runs well on other computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your css is in the following directory:

```
/public/css/blog-home.css
```

You can try the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/blog-home.css">
```

Have a read at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix

Comment: Are you using npm? if so, please try `npm install` then `npm run dev` in terminal.

Comment: No.I use php artisan serve

Comment: Okay, can you view your website, then right click and view source? Then update your question where we can see your `<link>` tags. :)

Comment: this addressing not working for me when I use php artisan serve and enter 127.0.0.1:8000 in url..but it work well when i use localhost/laravel.what is wrong with php artisan serve?

Comment: serve should not be used when in production. It is just setting up a temporary web server for you, when you stop serve, it will shut down. You need a proper web server (apache, nginx, etc) set up to host your website. Your web server needs to be configured correctly. I don't know your server configuration so I can't really say why it works or not. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34978918/1474817

Answer (score 0):

Simply refer your stylesheets to the public folder public/css/style.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
```

If you have multiple style sheets and want to mix them run laravel mix

```
mix.styles([
    'public/css/vendor/style.css',
    'public/css/vendor/fontrian.css' //and other style sheets
], 'public/css/all.css');

npm run dev
```

This will compile all your plain css to the public folder automatically.

Comment: I use this:<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">.but problem not fix yet

Comment: Where are your css files located?