# Laravel - Vue.js application not working without php artisan serve

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I have been trying to run my vue.js app with laravel, without

> php artisan serve

But been seriously failing, here is my code:

package.json:

```
"axios": "^0.17",
"bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
"cross-env": "^5.1",
"jquery": "^3.2",
"laravel-mix": "^1.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"vue": "^2.5.7",
"vue-router": "^3.0.1"
```

app.js:

```
import './bootstrap'
import router from './routes'

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    router
});
```

routes.js:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
let routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: require('./components/site/layouts/main-page'),
        children: [
            {
                path: '/',
                component: require('./components/site/views/home')
            }
        ]
    }
];

export default new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    linkActiveClass: 'active',
    routes
});
```

main-page.vue:

```
<template>
<div>
    <header></header>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
</template>
```

home.vue:

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>
</template>
```

welcome.blade.php:

```
<div id="root">
     <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

I shall be much obliged if anyone can assist me by correcting my wrong.

Comment: Does is work with ```php artisan serve``` and why are you not doing it without the command?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: It's working fine with php artisan serve but without it, it's showing this <!---->, that is empty comment within the div.

Comment: It's within bootstrap.js

Comment: Because you using vue with laravel(welcome.blade.php), there are styles and scripts imports. You need to make Vue separate from Laravel and use the Laravel only as api.

Comment: Are you're using XAMPP or maybe other webservers that you don't want to use `php artisan serve`?

Comment: I am using wamp currently.

Comment: This site of mine has both app and web hence two different ports will be an issue, besides laravel claims that it supports vue out of the box, which I found quite true, but this puny issue is ruining everything.

Comment: I have also a Laravel/Vue app using XAMPP but I don't have a problem with it without using the command. Maybe you might check in your server config file.

Comment: @gil I have no idea why it's not working. Maybe it's because of the vue-router.