# How to run artisan commands on cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have made a chat app with Vue.js and Laravel. On my localhost it is working fine when I run PHP artisan serve command but when I access the public folder directly on the browser through c://http:localhost/folder_name it does not work I also wanted to know how can I run PHP artisan serve command on Cpanel hosting because the chat works when I run the PHP artisan serve command and then run the server and access it using localhost:8000

Comment: `php artisan serve` command is used for development, not in production. Your online hosting is likely to have apache/Nginx running, use that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978857/laravel-how-to-start-server-in-production

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel how to start server in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978857/laravel-how-to-start-server-in-production)

Comment: you guys mean to say my chat app will work well when i will make it live? i mean when i upload my code on live server?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have ssh or terminal access (which most shared hosting using cpanel don't give you by default), then you can't.

Other than that, you shouldn't be running `php artisan serve` to run applications in the wild, and should instead use the given server via cpanel. Most of the time, this is apache and you should put the web root directory under your homepage. Check out the given [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978857/laravel-how-to-start-server-in-production) mentioned in the comments.

If you still insist on using that command and you **do** have terminal access, check under the following menu: `cPanel >> Home >> Advanced >> Terminal`

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Access+the+Command+Line