# How do I get Laravel DOMPDF working with Sail?

Tags: php, laravel, vite, laravel-sail, laravel-dompdf

I have a project using Laravel 10 and [Lando](https://lando.dev/) for a local dev environment. We recently implemented [Laravel DOMPDF](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) to turn a Blade template into a PDF.

This has been working fine, so long as we run `lando npm run build` rather than `lando npm run dev` so that it builds the stylesheet file in the correct directory and Vite links to the correct file.

Now I have implemented Laravel Sail, which also uses Vite, for our local dev environment as an alternative to Lando. It works perfectly *except* for Laravel DOMPDF. It seems unable to find the linked stylesheets and images, so the resulting PDF is unstyled and missing all the images.

Nothing has changed in the `vite.config.js` file, and the only thing I changed in `.env` is altering `APP_URL=http://nexus.lndo.site/` to `APP_URL=http://localhost/`.

Here's the `vite.config.js` file:

```js
/// <reference types="vitest" />
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import svgLoader from 'vite-svg-loader';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        https: false,
        host: true,
        port: 3009,
        hmr: {
            host: 'localhost',
            protocol: 'ws',
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
            script: {
                defineModel: true,
            },
        }),
        svgLoader()
    ],
    test: {
        globals: true,
        environment: 'happy-dom',
        setupFiles: ['./resources/js/tests/setup.js'],
        unstubGlobals: true,
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'ziggy-js': path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.es.js'),
            // 'vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.es.js' if using the Vue plugin
        },
    },
});
```

And here is a snippet of the `dispatch-sheet.blade.php` file that is used for the PDF rendering.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'IEL Nexus') }}</title>

    <!-- Google fonts needed since Font Bunny doesn't work with dompdf -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Homemade+Apple&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,700;1,400;1,500;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    @vite('resources/css/app.css')
    <style>
        body {
            font-size: 10px;
        }

        .font-sans {
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        }

        .font-signature {
            font-family: 'Homemade Apple', handwriting, cursive;
        }
        dt {
            float: left;
            font-weight: bold;
            clear: both;
            padding-top: 5px;
        }

        dd {
            padding-top: 5px;
            text-align: right;
        }

        .w-third {
            width: 33%;
        }

        .w-fifth {
            width: 20%;
        }

        .w-two-fifths {
            width: 40%;
        }

        .w-quarter {
            width: 25%;
        }

        .w-half {
            width: 50%;
        }

        td {
            padding-top: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body class="font-sans">
    <table class="w-full border-separate table-fixed border-spacing-2">
        <tr>
            <td class="w-two-fifths pl-2 align-top">
                <img src="{{ asset('images/logo-ratecon.png') }}" alt="RateCon Logo">
            </td>
            <td class="w-two-fifths px-2 align-top">
                <p><strong>Dispatch Sheet</strong></p>
                <p>
                    Integrity Express Logistics<br>
                    PO Box 42275 - Cincinnati, OH 45242<br>
                    Tel.: 937-502-1024 Ext: 1024 - Fax: 855-600-2467 - Email: {{ $customer_email }}
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="w-fifth pl-2 align-top text-right">
                <strong>IEL PO#: {{ $po_number }}</strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<!-- … -->
```

My guess is that Sail is doing something different when using Vite to compile the CSS file, specifically using a different path than Lando. What could that be?

Comment: Is DOMPdf run in a web process or a background process? Either way you should be able to collect stdout/stderr from it, which presumably would reveal an error about a missing CSS file.

Comment: I do not know what process it uses to render the pdf file. I also do not know how to read from stdout/stderr, could you please explain the best way to do so? I _have_ checked the laravel.log file, but DOMPDF doesn't seem to dump any information there at all.

Comment: Does DOMPDF run at the same time as the PDF output is requested over the web?

Comment: No. It is generated and then attached to an email message.

Comment: Right, so it is a background process. What generates it? Is there a queue or a scheduler?

Comment: Can you stop this process from running temporarily and run it manually from the console? I wonder if the standard output/error streams would be more evident then.

Comment: We are running it inside of a Laravel Notification. Since they implement the `ShouldQueue` interface, they are queued like a Job. I do not know how to run it from the console, since it is a PHP process.

Comment: OK, but PHP processes do not spin up by themselves. Something must create one. In theory one can create a background process from inside a web process, but it is usually creates a process permissions mess. I think the next step is to determine what queuing system you have in operation.

Comment: AFAIK, the queuing process is Laravel Queue, since it is in a Notification class that implements the ShouldQueue interface. Is that what you are referring to? `class DispatchSheetReadyNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue {…}`

Comment: It sounds about right. But Laravel Queue is probably still PHP - so what triggers that?

Comment: [This doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#connections-vs-queues) give some possible answers to my question: Amazon SQS, Beanstalk, or Redis. Any suggestions from those?

Comment: Ah, I think the above are just for storage. The same doc refers to Supervisord, which is what triggers a queue worker. Could you stop Supervisor and then use `artisan queue:work`?

Answer (score 0):

Working with Tighten, a highly knowledgeable team of Laravel professionals, I finally have an answer.

I needed to set `PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS=3` in my `.env` file because Sail runs `php artisan serve` by default, which means that only has a single process. Therefore, it cannot run the web request to render the HTML + the asset fetching from the PDF renderer simultaneously. So, setting this environment variable to a number higher than 1 tells the PHP built-in web server to spin up more workers, which solves this issue.

Comment: [Per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34978918), Sail uses the built-in PHP web-server, which is OK in itself, but since it is not for prod usage, it means that you're working in an environment that is deliberately different to production. I wonder if there is value in containerising your app so that the delta between environments is reduced.